QueuePool limit of size 10 overflow 10 reached
I joined the one project and I make the backend with flask and Flutter is the front end.When I started the emulator, I got the following error.
sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 10 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30.00 (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/3o7r)

It seems like I have to edit  pool size but I can’t find it in the project.
My assumption “It seems like I have edit  pool size ”get to the core?
I did search pool size section in project but I can't find it.

You configure pool size when creating the engine. But if you are hitting the limit in development it is possible that you are not managing your sessions correctly, that is they are not being closed at the end of each request.

Thank you I reboot docker and it works again!
